# Error when dismissing ProgressDialog - E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Apologies, I know this question has been asked a couple times.
But I've tried the suggested solution and have had no success.

In my Android app, I started randomly getting this error out of nowhere, I didn't modify the code, it ran fine a couple of times, and now it shows me this error:

```
`E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`
```

[image: logcat]

It happens when I call my java class where I set up a BluetoothConnectionService. Specifically, it occurs when the method to dismiss a Progress Dialog box is called.

```
`public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket mSocket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting");

        mmBTSocket = mSocket;
        InputStream mTempIn = null;
        OutputStream mTempOut = null;
        // dismiss the progressdialog when the connection is established.
        try{
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Couldn't dismiss progressDialogBox" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        try {
            mTempIn = mmBTSocket.getInputStream();
            mTempOut = mmBTSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Failed to get I/O Stream: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        mInStream = mTempIn;
        mOutStream = mTempOut;
    }`
```

In the Dialog.java file, I think it is occurring in this method.

```
`@Override
public void dismiss() {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == mHandler.getLooper()) {
        dismissDialog();
    } else {
        mHandler.post(mDismissAction);
    }
}`
```

Previous suggestions for this error which I have found here on stackoverflow, haven't worked. I have tried adding the following code to my AndroidManifest which didn't work:

```
`       android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"`
```

Please, any suggestions would help as I had the app mostly finished before this started happening and I can't figure out why!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your context is getting null. This mostly happens when context or view to which you are pointing becomes null. Just try to implement following checks before calling that:

```
 if ( getContext() != null && getView != null )
 {
      // do your stuff here
 }
```

Also you need to update views on main thread. If you are not on a main thread then you should implement handler to update your UI components. Visit following link for details:

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui

Do the following:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(); // write in onCreate function

 handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    // Update your UI components here
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I added the getContext check, and it is not null. I can't check getView, as the class doesn't have a view. It doesn't have an onCreate function either. The class is essentially identical to this [link](https://github.com/mitchtabian/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Bluetooth/blob/master/Bluetooth-Communication/app/src/main/java/com/example/user/bluetooth_communication/BluetoothConnectionService.java). The equivalent error occurs on line 230. With regard to declaring a handler, where should I declare it if I don't have an onCreate function?

Comment: Replace this line : mProgressDialog.dismiss(); with mProgressDialog.dismiss(getContext()); after that replace `@Override
public void dismiss() {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == mHandler.getLooper()) {
        dismissDialog();
    } else {
        mHandler.post(mDismissAction);
    }
}
with:
`@Override
public void dismiss(Context context) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == mHandler.getLooper()) {
        
if(context!=null){dismissDialog();}
    } else {
        mHandler.post(mDismissAction);
    }
}

Comment: This will work if issue is in that line as you said otherwise you have to debug to get to the exact point where exception is.

Comment: Where should I implement the dismiss override method? I implemented it in the Dialog.java file that the debugger brought me to when finding the error: _(C:\...\Android\SDK\sources\android-22\android\app\Dialog.java)_. But it doesn't effect my code (i.e. when calling dissmiss(getContext()) it still doesn't think dismiss takes context as an argument). I also implemented it on the Android-27 SDK file (the app's compileSDKversion), but still have the error. Should I be implementing this elsewhere? Why isn't the edited dismiss method which takes a context updating in my other class?